# How to modify the content load from the url with UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I load a webpage with a url in webview,
and I want to replace all the "android" word in that page with "iOS",
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UIWebView`'s `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method to modify your HTML once it has been loaded:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('android').innerHTML = iOS]];
```

for sample [link](http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2012/04/uiwebview-javascript-and-objective-c.html)

Comment: @CarrieOu -- happy to hear this, if my answer is useful give the upvote for the answer